# Vectorized operations in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of 5 numpy arrays, each with 5 observations. I need to use the trapezoid rule of integration to get 5 results of integrating. I'm trying to use for loop for apply a function to each numpy array and looking for something that has faster implementation.

```
def trapezoid_rule(a,b,n,f_nparray):
  h = (b-a) / (n-1)
  return (h/2) * (f_nparray[0] + 2 * sum(f_nparray[1:n-1]) + f_nparray[n-1])

simulation_res = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [1,3,5,7,9], [1,4,2,5,7], [1,5,2,6,4], [6,2,5,3,4]])

# List of integration results
I = []

for i in simulation_res:
  I.append(trapezoid_rule(0,1,10,i))
```

Expected output format = [a,b,c,d,e]

Comment: try something like `(f_nparray[:, [0]] + 2 * sum(f_nparray[:, 1:n-1]) + f_nparray[:, [n-1]])` - applying the `trapezoid_rule` function to all rows at once.  The trickiest part is getting the 3 terms to work together, with the `rules of broadcasting`.  shapes: (n,1), (n,m), (n,1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without `for` loops, but I'll show both. `numpy` has a built-in trapezoidal rule that works in a vectorized way. If you wanted to use it:

```
import numpy as np

simulation_res = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], 
                           [1,3,5,7,9], 
                           [1,4,2,5,7], 
                           [1,5,2,6,4], 
                           [6,2,5,3,4]])
result = np.trapz(simulation_res, axis=1)
print(result) 
# Gives [12.  20.  15.  15.5 15. ]
```

However if the loop is required for some reason, you could just preallocate some memory in a `numpy` array and append it

```
result = np.zeros(5)
for idx, i in enumerate(simulation_res):
    result[idx] = np.trapz(i)
print(result)
# Gives [12.  20.  15.  15.5 15. ]
```

Comment: How do I provide the limits of integral in the first approach? I'm trying -

Comment: From what I understand, this numerical quadrature method uses the `dx` of the array. To specify limits, you would either need a vector function `f(x)` or know the indices of the start and stop points in the array when you pass it to `trapz`. If you want to utilize the limits, look at [`quad_vec`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad_vec.html). Alternatively @hpaulj gave an answer that works for your question.

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
def foo(a,b,n,f_nparray):
  h = (b-a) / (n-1)
  return (h/2) * (f_nparray[:,0] + 2 * np.sum(f_nparray[:,1:n-1], axis=1) + f_nparray[:,n-1])

In [20]: foo(0,1,5,simulation_res)
Out[20]: array([3.   , 5.   , 3.75 , 3.875, 3.75 ])
```

which matches your `I`.

I had to add `axis` to `np.sum`; and in contrast to my comment, just use `0` for the indexing.  I just need one value per row of the 2d array.

Compared to `np.trapz`:

```
In [29]: np.trapz(simulation_res, axis=1)/4
Out[29]: array([3.   , 5.   , 3.75 , 3.875, 3.75 ])

In [30]: timeit np.trapz(simulation_res, axis=1)/4
34 µs ± 1.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [31]: timeit foo(0,1,5,simulation_res)
25.7 µs ± 139 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```